# Laravel RedirectifAuthenticated not working with multiple custom guards

Tags: laravel

I have two authentication guards `adminuser` and `customer`.
I edited `RedirectIfAuthenticated` middleware but when I login as a customer it will redirect to the page that is setup for authenticated admins (i.e admin dashboard view).
But I need to redirect customer back to home page after login.

Why does the customer login redirect to admin dashboard?

here is the `RedirectifAuthenticated` middleware

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if ($guard === "adminuser" && Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/adminhome');
    }
    if ($guard === "customer" && Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/customerhome');
    }
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/customerhome');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

`LoginController.php`

```php
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    $this->middleware('guest:adminuser')->except('logout');
    $this->middleware('guest:customer')->except('logout');
}

// login for the Admin user
public function userLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
            'username'   => 'required|min:3',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|max:6'
    ]);
    $status = Auth::guard('adminuser')->attempt(['email' => $request->username, 'password' => $request->password]);
    if ($status == true) {
            return redirect()->intended('/adminhome');
    } else {
            $request->session()->flash('error', 'Sorry,Login Unuccessfull!');
            return redirect()->back();
    }
}

// login for the customer
public function customerLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
            'username' => 'required|min:3',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|max:6'
    ]);

    $status = Auth::guard('customer')->attempt(['email' => $request->username, 'password' => $request->password], $request->get('remember'));
    if ($status == true) {
            return redirect()->intended('/customerhome');
    } else {
            return redirect()->intended('/customerhome');
    }
}
```

Here are the routes

```php
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/index', 'FrontController@index')->name('index');
Route::get('/admin/login', 'adminloginController@ShowAdminLoginForm') > name('adminLogin');  //route for admin login page

Route::post('/register', 'FrontController@storeRegister');

Route::post('/payment', 'PaymentController@processpayment');

Route::post('/customerLogin', 'Auth\LoginController@customerLogin');
Route::post('/adminUserLogin', 'Auth\LoginController@userLogin');

Route::view('/adminhome', 'home');
Route::view('/customerhome', 'index');
```

Comment: Try adding a `dd()` inside the middleware and checking what guard is active.

Comment: Check what you are getting in $guard variable inside Middleware. Using dd($guard);

Comment: thanks i'll try that out.

Comment: I tried using dd($guard); it returns null, i don't understand the problem. i'm new to Laravel.